# setting variables with vpa in loops

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision, symbolic-math, arbitrary-precision

I am trying to set a variable by [`vpa`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) (variable-precision arithmetic). If I try

```
a=vpa(tanh(1))
```

then `a=0.76159415595576485102924380043987` as desired. Now I try to do it in a loop:

```
a=[];
for i=1:3
    a(i)=vpa(tanh(1));
end
```

However, now when I output `a(1)`, I just get the value `0.761594155955765`. Why don't I get the last digits as I did in the first case?

Comment: How do you output `a(1)`? On my machine, `vpa(a(1))` returns `0.76159415595576485102924380043987`. If you do it with `fprintf`, then it's converted to double precision before output.

Comment: @2mkgz: That's because `a` is a double. Applying `vpa` to the vector `a` *after* the calculation works in this case because that operation is the last one performed on each element. There are actually two issues with the question – see my answer below.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the clarification. At first I expected the reason to be type coercion at `a(i)=vpa(tanh(1))` but then got confused by `vpa(a(1))` seemingly "restoring" lost precision.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code.

First, if you run `class(a)` after your `for` loop you'll see that `a` is a `'double'` rather than a `'sym'`. The reason for this is because you initially allocated `a` as an empty double precision array: `a = [];`. Each time you insert symbolic variable precision values into this, they are cast to be the same class as `a`.

To properly build a symbolic array, you need to allocate as such:

```
a = sym([]);
for i = 1:3
    a(i) = vpa(tanh(1));
end
a
class(a)
```

Even better, specify the final size:

```
n = 3;
a = sym(zeros(n,1)); % Or a = zeros(n,1,'sym');
for i = 1:n
    a(i) = vpa(tanh(1));
end
a
class(a)
```

In your case, both of the above options are equivalent to the following because you're applying `vpa` as the last operation on each element:

```
n = 3;
a = zeros(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    a(i) = tanh(1);
end
a = vpa(a);
```

This leads to the second issue, which is that your calculations are not really taking advantage of variable precision. You need to make sure that all values are converted to symbolic or variable precious before performing operations on them. For example:

```
a = vpa(tanh(1)) % Calculate tanh(1) as double then convert to vpa
b = tanh(vpa(1)) % Calculate tanh(1) using actual variable precision
a-b
```

returns `0.000000000000000037090214482164921742783153748416`. In other words, `vpa(tanh(1))` calculates the hyperbolic tangent in double precision and `tanh(vpa(1))` does so using variable precision.